# Word for a person that is being taken advantage of financially / leeched off

Tags: single-word-requests

In English there is the concept of somebody who is a 'leech', and takes advantage of a second person's resources or generosity, financially or otherwise.

What word or phrase could be used to denote **the one who is leeched from**?

I don't mind whether there are positive or negative connotations to the word - "sugar daddy" is a good American example but not suitable for my (British / Scottish) context. To me this is a good example because it explicitly implies the ongoing leeching relationship, and is not simply an attribute of the person.

*edit: In the specific usage I'm looking for, the provision is given consciously by the second party. Beyond that, I don't mind whether the giving relationship is willing or reluctant, personally (e.g. parent) or impersonally (e.g. bank). The word or phrase must function sensibly in the following sentence: "I am not your _____"*

Comment: Sticking with the metaphoric imagery suggested by ***leech***, the victim could be a ***sucker***. But I don't see how ***sugar daddy*** relates to the concept being queried.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers - have updated the question to clarify why I consider it a good word for the context.

Comment: "Victim" is the usual term.

Comment: @HotLicks - really? If a person 'leeches' off their parents or a friend or an organisation, is the latter well described as their 'victim'? Seems a bit strong.

Comment: I've seen some very muscular leaches.

Comment: The edit helped, but specific context is still missing. Has the person been deceived? Who initiated the relationship and how forceful was the come-on? What is the giver's motivation? As it stands, your question is still far too broad and will tend to generate opinions, not answers. Please provide a concrete context and a fill-in-the-blank sentence.

Comment: In banking jargon: customers

Comment: It's curiously backwards for this guy and a lollipop.They are both called suckers.

Comment: Sugar daddies aren't the victims of parasites; rather, they pay for services rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English a person is often called a ***mug*** if they have allowed someone to take advantage of them (it's a little like being the *mark* of a scam, but with *mark* you don't know whether the scam succeeded or failed—with *mug* you know it worked). I think it's a carney term.

You probably wouldn't say "I'm not *your* mug" but you'd say "I'm not *a* mug"—or "Do you take me for a mug?" or "What sort of mug do you think I am?"

American English gives us ***chump*** and ***sucker*** along the same lines.

Comment: "I'm not *your* mug" - that gave me a good laugh. This does 'feel' like the best fit, and so I'll accept it under the assumption there probably isn't an ideal word for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You could say "a soft touch", but this is a more general characteristic meaning that the person is easily tricked or taken advantage of, and doesn't capture the "one side of a specific relationship" aspect.

> 1. a person who is easily convinced, especially to give or lend money:
> 2. a person who is easily influenced, duped, or imposed upon:

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/soft-touch))

Answer (score 4):

I think '[prey](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prey)' could fit the bill if you think 'victim' (suggested by @Hotlicks) is a bit strong.

> One that is deceived or taken advantage of by another: '*easy prey for swindlers*'

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition]

Answer (score 2):

*"I am not your **servant**"* (or ***subject***, or other synonyms)

**Servant** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/servant)

> *noun* a person who serves others

**Subject** — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/subject)

> *noun* 11. a person or thing under the control or influence of another.

Comment: It looks like this might be as close as I'm going to get... will mark this as right if nothing else comes through in the next few days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A person that is *soft in character*, is easily lured into doing things that might not be in favor of her/his own interests.

Answer (score -3):

I was thinking maybe 'schmuck' would fit.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Please consider adding a dictionary reference or quote to support your answer.